# Как получить название объекта дескриптора и класса в котором дескриптор инициализируется python?

Tags: python

Появилось два вопрос: как в дескрипторе получить имя объекта самого дескриптора? Как в дескрипторе получить имя класса в котором был инициализирован дескриптор?

Для примера прилагаю код:

```
class Descriptor:
    def __init__(self):
        #Здесь нужно получить название объекта "b" и название класса "A"

class A:
    b = Descriptor()
```

Comment: Эм.. А зачем это?

Comment: @Qwertiy на деле все обстоит так: название объекта(в примере - "b") служит названием поля в в таблице. Соответственно, при инициализации дескриптора название поля должно добавляться в __dict__ класса(в примере - "A")

Answer (score 2):

На момент инициализации экземпляра `Descriptor()` класс `A` даже еще не существует.

```py
class Descriptor:
    def __init__(self):
        print('A' in globals()) # False

class A:
    b = Descriptor()

print('A' in globals()) # True
```

А после того, как он будет создан, `'b'` и так будет ключом в словаре класса `A`, который будет указывать на экземпляр дескриптора

```py
print(A.__dict__['b']) # <__main__.Descriptor object at 0x7f369ca9a6a0>
```

Так что непонятно, зачем вам понадобилось делать эту работу самостоятельно.

Дескриптор связывается с экземпляром (или классом) в момент обращения, а не в момент создания, так что экземпляр (или класс), с которым он связан, можно получить из метода `__get__` дескриптора.

```py
class Descriptor:
    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        print("Class:", cls.__name__)
        if obj is not None:
            return "значение"
        else:
            return self

class A:
    b = Descriptor()

print(A().b)
print(A.b)
```

При этом `A.__dict__['b']` вернет именно экземпляр дескриптора, а не значение, которое он может вернуть в `__get__` вместо `self`

```py
class Descriptor:
    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        return "значение"

class A:
    b = Descriptor()

print(A().b) # значение
print(A.b) # значение
print(A.__dict__['b']) # <__main__.Descriptor object at 0x7f8ef435e6a0>
```

#### Дополнение по вопросу в комментариях

```py
import inspect

def update_descriptors(cls):
    cls.descriptors = {f'_column#{attr}': value
                       for attr in dir(cls)
                       for value in [inspect.getattr_static(cls, attr, default=None)]
                       if isinstance(value, Descriptor)}
    return cls

class Descriptor:
    pass

@update_descriptors
class A:
    a = Descriptor()
    b = Descriptor()

@update_descriptors
class B(A):
    c = Descriptor()

print(B.descriptors) # {'_column#a': ..., '_column#b': ..., '_column#c': ...}
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ! Возможно ли переопредилить добавление этого дескриптора в __dict__ класса "A"? Мне нужно чтобы к "b"(в примере) прибавлялось "_column#", чтобы в результате получилось "_column#b"

Comment: @АртемСоколов Ну можно наверное, вопрос когда. В момент инициализации нельзя - добавлять пока некуда. После создания класса можно, но требуется дополнительное действие, его можно спрятать, например, в декоратор, но совсем от него избавиться вряд ли получится. Обновил ответ.